# Strict graph which displays multiple edges differently

Tags: graphviz, edges

Grouping [multiple edges together is possible by defining the graph as strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300586/590790).

From [the Graphviz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/cgi-bin/man?dot):

> If the graph is strict then multiple edges are not allowed between the
>   same pairs of nodes.

What I am interested in however, is whether I can define some 'behavior' *how to* group them together. For example, I would be interested in adding a label showing how many edges have been grouped together, or changing the thickness of the arrow.

Is something similar possible using Graphviz directly? I suppose I could do my own preprocessing but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

Note that grouping edges together is actually defined with:

```
concentrate="true";
```

But what you ask (adding a label or thickness of the edge/arrow) can easily be done by adding attributes to your edges.  For example:

```
A -> B [penwidth="4.5"];
```

Adding a label to the edge uses the same "[...]" format:

```
A -> B [label="8 edges have been combined"];
```

Sometimes you might want a line to go from the label to the edge:

```
A -> B [label="this is my edge" decorate="true"];
```

The arrowhead size is also an attribute of the edge.  While I haven't tried this one, the documentation says `arrowsize` is "Multiplicative scale factor for arrowheads."  I would try this:

```
A -> B [arrowsize="2.0"];
```

Lastly, note you can combine attributes.  For example:

```
A -> B [label="test" penwidth="5" decorate="true" arrowsize="4.1"];
```

Source:  http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs

Comment: Yup ... that was easy enough to figure out, but it still involves preprocessing. :) You could update your answer to state that without preprocessing (and e.g. adding the attributes you listed) this is not possible in GraphViz. That is also how I ended up doing it eventually ...