# How to create double labelled edges in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I would like to create more than one label for one edge. The result I'm interested in looks like this:

[image]

Note that the edge {0,2} has two labels: e and z. One is above the edge, the other one - below. This is the exact outcome I want. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
digraph G {
  graph [ splines = false rankdir="LR" ]
  a -> b [ label = "foo" ];
  a -> b [ label = "bar" ];
}
```

I've checked it using http://www.webgraphviz.com/

Result looks like

[image: Two labels]

Taken from stackoverflow question [Graphviz, grouping the same edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324486/graphviz-grouping-the-same-edges)

Comment: I haven't. When I get home I will try this method and get back to you. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @MatthewRock, remember, it's just a trick to workaround this issue, [have a look at the documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines). Still, it is really good question about the possibility to have multiple labels at once

Comment: @MatthewRock, thanks for accepting answer, but I remind again that my solution is a trick. In case one day this feature will be implemented and someone will give better answer - reaccept it. Right now, unfortunately, I don't see another option

Comment: I am aware of this. Unfortunately, this isn't the best solution either for edges that aren't horizontal but are more curvy or such, but still the average fix is better then no fix.